# Asynchronus streams and global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to learn some `node.js` and asynchronus event juggling and encountered a problem.

Say I have `n` different node.js stream readables which I can get. Each produces `data` events which I want to store. When all the streams are finished, I want to log all their results in the console. What I have so far:

```
outputs = [];
//Construct an array in which the outputs will wait for the streams to finish:
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
     outputs.push('');
}
ended = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    var ithReadable = getReadableStreamSomehow(i); // produces the i-th readable stream.
    ithReadable.on('data', function(chunk){
        outputs[i] += chunk;
    });
    ithReadable.on('end', function(chunk){
        ended++;
        if (ended == n){
            console.log(outputs);
        }
    });
}
```

The idea behind this code is this:

For each `i` from `0` to `n-1`, the code starts to listen to the i-th readable stream, producing `2n` functions listening on the streams. As a stream produces a `data` event, I want to store it into the `i`-th output. When all streams are finished, I print out their results.

The code I provided is not working. As I understand, the problem is that as `i` changes from 1 to 2, the functions that were written to listen on the `1`-th stream now want to write to `outputs[2]` not on `outputs[1]`, making a god awful mess.

My question is thus:

I do know that what I want to do is best achieved through `pipe`s. However, this is about me learning the principles of async programming and want to push through in this manner. How can I avoid a situation like the one above where global variables (`i`) are messing with my callback functions? Is there a way to do the exact things I wanted to do (but actually working, of course)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a new variable in its own scope that will not be modified by the for loop.  I recommend a closure.

Observe the difference between these two chunks of asyncronous code, and try running them in Chrome's console:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){ //This function is asynchronous.
     console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Version 2:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  // This anonymous function executes immediately, once per loop, and is not asynchronous
  (function(){         
     var k = i;  // once k is instantiated it will not be modified again.
     setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(k);
     }, 1000);
  })();  
}
```

Per request, the efficient version which doesn't create as many functions in a loop.  If setTimeout took a third parameter in Node (the argument to pass to the callback), we could also create the anonymous function used in `setATimeout` before the loop runs.

```
function setATimeout(i){
   // i was passed by value since it is a primitive, so no scope problems.
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i); 
     }, 1000);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setATimeout(i);
}
```

Comment: I would like to note that this code may be written more efficiently, e.g. not creating functions in a loop.  But this was written to be readable.

Comment: Create a new closure where the value doesn't change. Nice

Comment: Thank you very much. If the closure would be a function dependent on `i`, this would again not work, am I correct?

Comment: @AlexMA, do you mind adding the more efficient implementation in your answer. I'm not sure what it would look like.

Comment: Sure, see new version.  The key is to define the functions outside of the loop.

Comment: Version 2.1 - IIFE
`for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

  // This anonymous function executes immediately, once per loop, and is not asynchronous

  (function(k){         

     //k is local it will not be modified again.

     setTimeout(function(){

        console.log(k);
     }, 1000);
  })(i);  // pass i to anonymous function
}`

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how to format code in comment. Added as a sep. answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. Javascript's Function constructor allows you to define a function body as a string:

```
ithReadable.on('data', new Function("chunk", "outputs[" + i + "] += chunk;");
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: This looks like it should work, but it looks very hacky to me. Is there no general way to provide callback functions with variables they should manipulate (as in: you, the function I just created, always change the i-th value, where i is 4. Ignore whatever else I am doing with `i`from now on)

Comment: I'm interested in this myself. Like if only there was someway to pass in a parameter to the callback

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

You should be careful when you use up-closure-scope variables in javascript.

Java requires closure variables to be final value.

Unlike Java, Javascript allows modifying closure variables.

In this case, you should pass values within some object not by closure variable.

Fortunately, node.js passes "this" when it calls back for event handling.

```
ithReadable.idx = i;
ithReadable.on('data', function(chunk){
    outputs[this.idx] += chunk;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on @AlexMA with IIFE version

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  // This anonymous function executes immediately, once per loop, and is not asynchronous
  (function(k){
     //k is local it will not be modified.
     setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(k);
     }, 1000);
  })(i);  // pass i to anonymous function
}
```